# EventBus is not triggered in fragments android

Tags: android, android-fragments, greenrobot-eventbus

What Am I doing:

### I have a subscriber in `MainActivity.Java`

I have registered in `OnStart` of activity

```
@Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        //Register the event bus for the screen
        EventBus.getDefault().register(this);

    }


@Subscribe(threadMode = ThreadMode.MAIN)
public void onMessageEvent(BusCategories event) {
        //On Click of Categories Label

}
```

---

### Then, I have a Publisher in the `FragmentA` which is

```
EventBus.getDefault().post(new BusCategories(mUploadProducts.getCategories()));
```

---

***So a event in Fragment is triggered calls in main activity***

1. This Is working, but say I go to power save mode in phone where
   onPause is triggered and come back again the subscriber never gets
   triggered
2. How to properly handle this

Comment: I wouldn’t subscribe in `onCreate` but rather either `onStart` or `onResume` and would (respective) unsubscribe on `onStop` or `onPause` (depending which one you chose).

Comment: @MartinMarconcini how subscribing in onStart or onResume solves the issue here?

Comment: Until we see what the OP is doing in either method, it’s impossible to tell given the amount of provided information. However, I would still follow the practice of using the lifecycle as intended. Not to mention I wouldn’t use an event bus to begin with…

Comment: On registering on OnStart .. does solve the issue ... but why we need to register again and again ... when we can do only once in onCreate

Comment: Ah… that’s the topic for another question ;-)

Comment: @Devrath when you were unregistering it before? in which life cycle?

Comment: I was unregistering in `OnDestroy` of activity

Comment: Strange..!! in that case, it should work.

Comment: @Ritesh ... Sorry I was unregistering in OnStop .... that was the issue .... After unregistering in OnDestroy ... its working .... 
Best practice would be OnCreate .. register and OnDestroy unregister :)

Comment: @Ritesh may this serve as a lesson not to bash answers before having all the data. My comment was actually solving the issue because I had the idea that the OP was doing exactly what he’s doing. Yet you bashed me (ironically) trying to sound smart… chill, this is a free space and we’re all trying to help. Now… you @devrath… “best practice would be on create/ondestroy” is not true. It really depends, especially if you have fragments… but if it works for you, good. It really depends.

Comment: @MartinMarconcini Chill man..!! Check out his code, he has registered in onCreate(), and how it works if you do the same in onStart() or Stop(). I was curious so asked, as how it's possible.And, you should have answered the same instead of putting as "that's the topic for another question". And yes onCreate() and onDestory() is not a best practise, it actually depends on your usecase, normally the registering and unregistering should happen in onStart() and onStop(). And i did the right here..!!

Comment: @Ritesh and Martin ... Thanks Guys ... This discussion helped me understand EventBus better :)

Answer (score 0):

You should handle registering and unregistering in `onStart` and `onStop`methods or `onResume` and `onPause` methods respectively.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, you need to make the event nullable object if you are using Kotlin.
for example :

```
//this will not tigger by eventbus  
@Subscribe
fun onEvent(message Short){

}


//but will trigger by event bus  
@Subscribe
fun onEvent(message Short?){

}
```